# Is my grandfather eligible for an EEA Family Permit?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

The Schengen visa for my grandfather was approved last week. We plan to travel to the UK during his stay in order to visit friends and family there. According to my signed German "formal obligation letter" I am fully responsible for my grandfather during his stay.

Does this count as "dependancy", which is needed to get an EEA family permit?

> Who are an EEA National’s Family Members?
>
> **> dependent direct relatives in the ascending line, for example parents
>   and grandparents of the EEA national or their spouse / civil partner.**

Thank you so much for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Likely not. Different countries operate with slightly different guidelines and documentation requirements for determining dependency, but the UK authorities guidelines state that your grandfather must be ['wholly or mainly financially dependent on the EEA principal (you) to meet his or her essential needs in order to qualify'](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eea-family-permits-eun02/eea-family-permit-eun02#eun29-how-do-i-establish-dependency-under-the-eea-regulations).

Your obligation letter only establishes a dependency for the costs directly related to your grandfathers visit in Germany and not any permanent dependency, as rather required for a family permit.